# My material texture seems blurry even after splitting it with mark seam

Tags: texturing

I have added leather texture on my model, but some parts of my model seem blurry even after I have split it with mark seam.

I have unwrap it again either and its still same. did i miss something?

*it solved now. thanks for your hints guys, it was helpfull to me. surely, i want to learn more about node shader. is there any Ebook, book, or website that i can use?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using a subdivision surface modifier on your model? Sometimes you need supporting geometry to prevent texture "warping".

Comment: It's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem (remember to pack the relevant image textures into the blend). The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DZG6GJ6n" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DZG6GJ6n/)

I has added my file on here. i has checked my model surface and it has 4 triangle surface on the bottom part. but iam not sure it was the problem.

Comment: and thanks for Duarte Farrajota Ramos and moonboots for fixed my post before. i has learn from both of you

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Looking at the UV map in the blend, that doesn't seem to be causing the problem, it's okay.  The "blurry" stretching/distortion on some of the faces seems to be caused by the Voronoi nodes not using the UV coordinates.  This can be fixed with a Texture Coordinate node's UV output into the Voronoi nodes' Vector inputs:

[image]

If by "blurry" you're referring to the Voronoi pattern, that can be controlled with a Color Ramp node after one or both of the Voronoi nodes:

[image]